# Page navigation is blocked by fetch request

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am using sveltekit for a project. When my current page makes a fetch request that takes a while and the user navigates to another page, it does not go to that page until the fetch request finishes.

```html
<script>
    // waits for this fetch when a tag is pressed
    let longFetch = fetch('/data.json');
</script>

<a href="/some-page">Some Page</a>
```

Is there a way to force the page to navigate regardless of ongoing requests?

None of the [link options](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/link-options) would solve this issue.

Earlier, my solution was to use `AbortController`, passing it to my a elements and calling `controller.abort()`.

```html
<script>
    const controller = new AbortController();

    let longFetch = fetch('/data.json', {
        signal: controller.signal
    });
</script>

<a href="/some-page" on:click={() => controller.close()}>Some Page</a>
```

But now this does not work. Looking at the network tab, when I click a link there is a `__data.json` request, but it's very slow and delayed until the `longFetch` is finished, even if it's aborted.

Comment: Can you show some code examples?

Comment: Is something stopping you from moving the API call into the page you're navigating to?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, the api call is for the current page not the navigating one. If you mean why I don't move it into the page's load function, that's because it's a long request, and I don't want the user to be stuck on loading for 30 seconds